# Swift - UISearchController filter multiple strings

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I am trying to get my UISearchController to filter through two strings. Here is my code.

Model:

```
var firstName: String
var lastName: String
```

I need the search bar to filter through both these names, but right now, its is filtering through one or the other, as soon as I add the space the filtering stops.

search controller code

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.filteredPlayers = filteredPlayers(for: searchController.searchBar.text)

    applySnapshot(animatingDifferences: true)
}

func filteredPlayers(for queryOrNil: String?) -> [VTRPlayer] {
    let players = self.players
    guard let query = queryOrNil, !query.isEmpty else { return players }
    return players.filter {
        // what you are searching
        return $0.lastName.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased()) || (($0.firstName.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased())))


    }
}
```

Comment: If you have "John Doe", "Johnna Doe", and you type in the search bar "John Do", what should you find? And if you type "John Do Mi"?

Comment: The space is a character as much as any other in the string, so unless there is a space at the end of the firstname or the start of the lastname it will never match.  You need to rethink you logic.  A basic solutions would be another case in your or that matches firstname + " " + lastname.  But there are nicer solutions...

Comment: @Larme in the case I type "John Do" I would expect to see John Doe but John and Doe are two different var names (firstName and lastName)

Comment: @flanker can you recommend one?

Answer (score 0):

when you add space in search bar the line below is trying to match search text in firstname or lastname with space.

$0.lastName.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased()) || (($0.firstName.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased())))

for Example: "Mary" string contains "Mary ".
So the case is failing and sending empty search results.

I think you can solve this 2 ways
**Option1:** by creating a model like below, so that you can search in whole name.

struct FullName{
var firstName: String,
var lastName: String,
var wholeName : String{
return "(firstName) (lastName)"
}
}

or
**Option2:**

let searchResult = players.filter {
**let whole = "($0.firstName) ($0.lastName)"**
return whole.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased()) || whole.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased())
}

Hope it helps!